# How To Prevent Darkmode.js from making background-image negative

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found `darkmode.js` (darkmodejs.learn.uno) a really easy way to implement dark mode in my website and it works superb with me expect a small problem. Which is, it changing the color of my background-image css property and making it a kind of negetive.

Is there any way to exclude the `background-image` from changing its color?

Hope for reply soon.

Thanks For Help In Advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding `isolation: isolate` to the same style of the background-image? If this also affects all the children, you could have the background-image in a separate pane behind the website in its own `div`

Comment: But it would isolate the whole ```div``` while I want to excluding only the background image of the div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. The [documentation](https://darkmodejs.learn.uno/#override-style) says you can override styles.

As the library will add a class `darkmode--activated` to the body of your page, you can write CSS selectors matching your background in enabled dark-mode:

```css
.darkmode--activated #my-element-with-background {
    filter: invert(0);
}
```

Please be aware that I don't know how exactly darkmode.js inverts you background. `filter: invert(1);` was just a wild guess. You'll have to examine what happens there and override the style property.